# change user permissions through code in drupal

Tags: drupal, permissions

I am new to Drupal.

I am working on a website where many different type of users are there. The requirement is to allow only bloggers to delete comments related to their blogs.

Yes i know that it can be done from admin. But the client is telling, they don't want to do it from admin rather that need to be achieved through code itself.

Please guide me from where (module, features etc) i need to write the code so that it will affect the permissions. And how that code should be written.

Any type of help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Export permissions with features module and use the same code as features generated. But remember: to use features functionality you need to revert feature after each code change

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal you can create Roles for the users.
You can specify what users will have the "blogger" role. And then, you can add permissions only for this role. In your case, you want to set the permission of delete comment.

I think you may find this link useful: https://drupal.org/node/120614

Regards.

Comment: Yes I have gone though that link. That link does not say anything about how I can achieve that through code. If i will want to check some of the check boxes as shown in your given URL, how can I do it through code? My requirement is, I should do that through code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link could help to create and set permissions programmatically. http://www.dibe.gr/blog/drupal-7-create-users-and-roles-programmatically

Otherwise, there is always Drupal official documentation: https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/user